# Correct terminology for a zero turn stator winding on a BLDC?

Tags: motors, terminology

I'm designing a BLDC motor with some unique geometry constraints (~250mm long, ~45mm diameter with a ~35mm bore down the center) and am considering using straight copper bars carrying high current instead of multiple turns around a core for the stater windings (motor needs to provide high torque at or close to stall for extended periods).

Are there existing motor designs that are similar that I could read up on? What would be the correct terminology to describe such a design so I can search for prior art on the subject?